# Is it possible to achieve the same efficiency of Coroutines but with Java?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I had an interview today. I was asked why Kotlin is better and I mentioned  *that with Kotlin we have Coroutines which makes it easier and so much better to perform heavy operations but with Threads(Java), if many threads are created and running at the same time it might cause out of memory issue.* And he replied, the same can be done with threads also in Java.
I'm a junior developer and I recently switched to kotlin, so my knowledge is limited about this and I can't find more about the same on the internet. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Coroutines uses the idea of suspending functions, which on the JVM uses state machines.  It is not directly tied to threads (Dispatchers in coroutines). There is no way of elimating "heavy" operations - thread blocking happens regardless. Kotlin advertises coroutines as a fantastic way to use callbacks inline and doesn't tie this directly to threading - but in 99.9% of usecases callbacks are usually because of asynchronous operations (like network calls) where you would use threading anyway.  The interviewer is referring to thread pools and executors much like coroutines use ie Dispatchers.IO

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine#Implementations_for_Java

Comment: Exactly what "efficiency" do you seek?

Comment: The main advantage of coroutines is that what you would have to do in Java using lambda function-oriented APIs (callbacks), with coroutines you can keep doing in the regular sequential programming style. Note that, when Project Loom becomes a part of Java, it will be even simpler than Kotlin coroutines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coroutines perform better than spawning many threads because they use thread pools under the hood, but thread pools are available in pure Java (Executor). The Kotlin documentation calls coroutines "lightweight threads", but really they are pieced-together from borrowed Threads. They are lighter weight than using one Thread per task, yes.

The advantage of coroutines over what can be done in Java is in the intuitive syntax for using them. Java requires a callback approach, which results in nested blocks and code that is written in a different order than its execution sequence.

Answer (score 5):

Everything you can do with coroutines can certainly be done in Java.  Coroutines are not magic; they're doing things you could do by hand.

It is much, much *harder* to get the same correctness, concision, and performance in pure Java.  Coroutines make it *easy* to accomplish all those things compared with what you'd have to write in equivalent Java.  Coroutines don't make anything new possible, they just make it easier to build and maintain.